# How fast is the SkyRanger?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

It's the end of the month near the start of a ironman classic game and I have 2 satellites to launch. A terror mission has just come up & one of the sites is currently at max terror; if I have time to get there, complete the mission and get back I can lower the panic and deploy my satellite to a more profitable location.

How fast is the Skyranger - I have less than 20 hours to get the mission done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be good. The Skyranger is much faster than the old aircraft from X-Com the First, and is able to respond to most missions (one way) in under 2 hours.

As point of comparison, I've recently run into a situation where I shot down an Alien UFO, and before I could launch a team to handle the crash, a Terror Site popped up (which is obviously going to be the priority).

Responding to the terror site shouldn't take any longer than 8 hours (and that's a conservative estimate), giving you plenty of time to launch your satellites before the council report.

Comment: I can confirm with some numbers. I just started playing the game recently, and it took something like four hours to get from Germany to Canada. Your agents should be safely back home in 20 hours.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "fast enough it delays everything else."  Turns out the council report won't come in while the Skyranger is on route to or returning from a mission.  Same for any event, actually, including facility construction or manufacturing.

If the report should happen during the flight, it will happen instead on the next time you click Mission Control.  Note that the event queue may lose track of the council report, and indicate it's 30 days until the next one, but don't let that worry you.

In summary: you can fly to the event, deal with it, and then launch satellites.  Just make sure you've launched them before you click on Mission Control, as the council report will be instant - it doesn't wait for you to click "Scan for Events."